# How can I rotate a vector 90 degrees into a perpendicular plane, and then 15 degrees free from that plane?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

What I ultimately want is a vector, giving the direction of the green line in the image below, knowing only the position of the yellow and green dots.

To be more specific, it's angle can be random as long as it's endpoint ends up somewhere on the green-blue surface of the cylinder. So, 360° free around cylinder, and about 15° limited to the edges of the cylinder.

The cylinder is perpendicular to the line from the yellow and green dot.

Length is not important, only direction.

My main problem is I don't know how to go from vector Yellow to green dot, to any vector perpendicular to it.

PS None of these things are aligned on a x y z axis. That grid is not xyz, just to help visualize.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code: given an angle theta and two points it will give you a vector starting from pointStart perpendicular to the vector from pointStart to pointEnd:

```js
function perpendicularVector(pointStart,pointEnd,theta){
    let vDiff = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)
        .subVectors(pointEnd, pointStart) 
        .normalize()
  
    let V = new THREE.Vector3(
        vDiff.y + vDiff.x * vDiff.z,
      vDiff.y * vDiff.z -vDiff.x,
      -(vDiff.x * vDiff.x) - vDiff.y * vDiff.y
    )

    return
        V   .applyAxisAngle(vDiff, theta)
            .applyAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3().multiplyVectors(V, vDiff).normalize(), 15*Math.PI/180 )
}
```

here is a small showoff of what the above code do: (the snippet is intentionally bad because its there just to show the functionality of the above code)

(you can zoom rotate and pan using the mouse on the render that appears after you click run snippet)

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e2cba9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="module">
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";

var scene = new THREE.Scene, theta = 0;
let point1 = new THREE.Vector3(4, 2, 1),
  point2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 3, 3);

function perpendicularVector(e, n, t) {
  let r = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0).subVectors(n, e).normalize(),
    o = new THREE.Vector3(r.y, -r.x, 0),
    i = new THREE.Vector3(r.x * r.z, r.y * r.z, -r.x * r.x - r.y * r.y);
  var a = o.multiplyScalar(Math.cos(t)).add(i.multiplyScalar(Math.sin(t)));
  return a.add(e), a
}

function pointAtCoords(e, n) {
  let t = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: n }),
    r = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.1, 8, 8),
    o = new
  THREE.Mesh(r, t);
  return o.position.add(e), o
}

function lineFromAtoB(e, n, t) {
  let r = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: t }),
    o = [];
  o.push(e), o.push(n);
  let i = (new THREE.BufferGeometry).setFromPoints(o);
  return new THREE.Line(i, r)
}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: !0 });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), document.getElementById("app").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  .1, 1e3);
camera.position.set(7, 7, 8), camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3), camera.position.add(new THREE.Vector3(3, 0, 3));
var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

function drawEverything(e) {
  const n = new THREE.AxesHelper(30);
  scene.add(n);
  const t = new THREE.GridHelper(30, 30);
  t.position.add(new THREE.Vector3(15, 0, 15)), scene.add(t);
  const r = new THREE.GridHelper(30, 30);
  r.rotateX(Math.PI / 2), r.position.add(new THREE.Vector3(15, 15, 0)), scene.add(r);
  const o = new THREE.GridHelper(30, 30);
  o.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2), o.position.add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 15, 15)), scene.add(o);
  let i = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
    a = perpendicularVector(point1, point2, e);
  scene.add(pointAtCoords(point1, 16776960)), scene.add(pointAtCoords(point2, 65280));
  var d = pointAtCoords(a, 255);
  scene.add(d), scene.add(lineFromAtoB(point1, point2, 16711935)), scene.add(lineFromAtoB(i, point1, 16711680)), scene.add(lineFromAtoB(i, point2, 16711680)), scene.add(lineFromAtoB(point1, a, 65280))
}

function animate() {
   scene = new THREE.Scene, drawEverything(theta += .1), 
   setTimeout((() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }), 1e3 / 30), renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate();
</script>
```

Comment: Looks right.  I don't understand the math. Especially because it uses x, y z, but maybe that's ok if you do all those tricks on it.  I'll try it whenever I have some time on my project. TBH, I thought this could be done with less vectors together with a certain three function (project plane or so)..

Comment: maybe there is some weird combination of functions in three that allows you to do this, but this is plain linear algebra you can't be more efficient

Comment: btw if you now need to tilt it 15dg or -15dg you can use a bit of linear algebra and combine the 2 vectors with some scalars to achieve the needed degree of tilt

Comment: the yellow/green vector and the perpendicular one

Comment: @e-motiv What do you mean you don't understand because it uses `x, y, z`? There is no simpler way of defining two points in 3D space, were you expecting something different?

Comment: I finally got time to integrate it. This works perfectly.  About, x, y, z, I didn't figure you needed x, y, z since you don't know where the start or end are in relation to theses axes, but I guess the logic or mathematics somehow need them after all....I finished algebra in college 20 years ago...so yeah... :-) .  Anyway, thank you!!!!

Comment: Hmm... I tried to add the ±15deg by some logic but it doesn't work. I will edit your code, improve it a bit and try to give tha 15deg, but it doesn't work..  Can you help me out?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, did you manage to add the 15 deg or you need help with that too?, its just some more vector algebra with the original vector to tilt the new one

Comment: you use x,y,z because you use vectors and not segments, you define the two points that make up the original line with 2 vectors (vectors start from the origin), then you find the diff VECTOR between them (that's the equivalent to the segment but starting from the origin) and normalize it to prepare for the transformations (otherwise you will get an ellipse and not a circle), after that you apply the transformations to it and you get a perpendicular VECTOR

Answer (score 0):

This is totally achievable with some math calculations. The term you're looking for is ["Orthogonal vectors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality), which means vectors that are perpendicular to each other. The cylinder radius is orthogonal to the line between blue to yellow points.

However, since you're already using Three.js, you can just let it do all the hard work for you with the help of [an `Object3D`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object3#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt).

```js
// Declare vectorA (center, green)
const vecA = new THREE.Vector3(xA, yA, zA);

// Declare vectorB (destination, yellow)
const vecB = new THREE.Vector3(xB, yB, zB);

// Create helper object
const helper = new THREE.Object3D();

// Center helper at vecA
helper.position.copy(vecA);

// Rotate helper towards vecB
helper.lookAt(vecB);

// Move helper perpendicularly along its own y-axis
const cylinderRadius = 27;
helper.translateY(cylinderRadius);

// Now you have your final position!
console.log(helper.position);
```

In the diagram below, the helper `Object3D` is shown as a red line only to give you a sense of its rotation and position, but in reality it is invisible unless you add a `Mesh` to it.

[image]

If you want to add/subtract 15 degrees from the perpendicular, you could just rotate the helper along its own x-axis **before** translateY()

```js
const xAngle = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(15);
helper.rotateX(xAngle);

const cylinderRadius = 27;
helper.translateY(cylinderRadius);
```

Comment: I don't really think this is it. Maybe I am wrong but...
I don't need a position, I need a direction. I already have the position. Also, why translateY? My points are random, not knowing where they are on x, y or z.