# OrbitControls on a shared camera cannot handle panning

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create two renderers on two different div containers.
Each renderer wish has its own OrbitControls for updating the associated camera.
The camera is shared between the two renderers.

The goal is to sync the camera for OrbitControl (so that two containers can have the same camera view) and render between the two render loops.

I noticed that the general rotation could be shared automatically. However, when I do panning, it behaves a bit strange. Here is a video:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5498964/170499367-44c2581d-8089-492e-bc90-a6675976bb44.mov

This is the minimum reproducible code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="rend1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="rend2" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>

<script type="module">
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const rend1 = document.getElementById("rend1")
const rend2 = document.getElementById("rend2")

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 2));
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

const r1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    precision: "highp",
    alpha: true,
  });
r1.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
const s1 = new THREE.Scene();
rend1.append(r1.domElement);

const c1 =  new OrbitControls(camera, r1.domElement)
s1.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(1));
s1.add(camera);
const g1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
const m1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0080ff} );
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(g1, m1);
s1.add(cube1)

const r2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    precision: "highp",
    alpha: true,
  });
r2.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
const s2 = new THREE.Scene();
rend2.append(r2.domElement);
const c2 =  new OrbitControls(camera, r2.domElement)
s2.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(1));
s2.add(camera);
const g2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
const m2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0080ff} );
const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(g2, m2);
s2.add(cube2)



const render1 = () => {
    r1.setSize(400, 400);
    c1.update();
    r1.render(s1, camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => render1());
};
const render2 = () => {
    r2.setSize(400, 400);
    c2.update();
    r2.render(s2, camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => render2());
};
render1 ();
render2 ();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the reason and how could we achieve desired behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution for this problem is to sync cameras and orbit control's target explicitly as they change. See `c1.addEventListener("change", () => { ... }}` and `c2.addEventListener("change", () => { ... }}`.

Here is a complete code for solving the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="rend1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="rend2" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>

<script type="module">
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const rend1 = document.getElementById("rend1")
const rend2 = document.getElementById("rend2")

const camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 0.01, 1000);
camera1.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 2));
camera1.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
const camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 0.01, 1000);
camera2.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 2));
camera2.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
const r1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    precision: "highp",
    alpha: true,
  });
r1.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
const s1 = new THREE.Scene();
rend1.append(r1.domElement);

const c1 =  new OrbitControls(camera1, r1.domElement)
s1.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(1));
s1.add(camera1);
const g1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
const m1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0080ff} );
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(g1, m1);
s1.add(cube1)
c1.addEventListener("change", () => {
    camera2.position.copy(camera1.position)
    camera2.rotation.copy(camera1.rotation)
    c2.target.copy(c1.target)
})

const r2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    precision: "highp",
    alpha: true,
  });
r2.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
const s2 = new THREE.Scene();
rend2.append(r2.domElement);
const c2 =  new OrbitControls(camera2, r2.domElement)
s2.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(1));
s2.add(camera2);
const g2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
const m2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0080ff} );
const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(g2, m2);
s2.add(cube2)
c2.addEventListener("change", () => {
    camera1.position.copy(camera2.position)
    camera1.rotation.copy(camera2.rotation)
    c1.target.copy(c2.target)
})




const render1 = () => {
    r1.setSize(400, 400);
    c1.update();
    r1.render(s1, camera1);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => render1());
};
const render2 = () => {
    r2.setSize(400, 400);
    c2.update();
    r2.render(s2, camera2);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => render2());
};
render1 ();
render2 ();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add your camera to any scene. The camera can be independent. Additionally, an Object3D can only have **one** parent, so when you do

```js
s1.add(camera);
s2.add(camera);
```

... then the camera only gets added to `s2`, because it automatically gets removed from `s1` when you assign a new parent.

Try removing all the `.add(camera)` from your code.

### Edit:

Additionally, you're adding two `CameraControls` to the same camera, then you're calling `c1.update()` and `c2.update()`. These two are giving conflicting commands to the camera because one control tells it to move, while the other one tells it to stay still. You should only use one control if you want to manipulate a single camera.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, no matter which `add(camera)` I remove from the code (including both), the panning behavior is still not that correct: either can pan from r1 or r2 but not working simoutainiously.

Comment: @Jakob Ah, then it would probably be best to show a working demo. You can add an executable code snippet [as demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71942146/2608515) or maybe sharing your code through https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Jakob I just noticed you're using two `Cameracontrols`, so I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but your suggestion doesn't entirely solve the issue. The problem is clear that two orbit control is conflicting when it is panning, but the real question, as being demonstrated in the video, is how to sync the states between two orbit control when mouse is editing them from different dom elements.